# Access to widget from topic.subscribe's callback

Tags: javascript, dojo, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use Dojo's pub/sub topic module as documented [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/events/). I am subscribing to an event inside a custom widget's `startup()` method and would like to modify the widget when the topic is triggered.

**How do I access the widget from the `topic.subscribe()` callback?** Inside the callback, `this` does not refer to the widget; I'm not sure what it refers to... the `this` object includes `emit` and `on` functions, as well as a `declaredClass` field that looks like `"uniqName_0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget has some convenience methods that will handle the hitch as phusick describes.

In the startup method, you can write

```
startup: function() {
  this.inherited(arguments);

  this.subscribe('topic/some', '_onTopic');
},

_onTopic: function() {
  this.something // 'this' is the widget
}
```

A widget has other convenience methods

```
this.unsubscribe
this.connect
this.disconnect
```

When using the `subscribe` and `connect` methods, the `unsubscribe` and `disconnect` methods will be automatically called when the widget is destroyed.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/_WidgetBase

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `dojo/_base/lang::hitch` to change the scope of callback function when subscribing inside the widget method, where `this` refers to the widgets instance. You have a couple of options here:

1. anonymous function:

   ```
   topic.subscribe("topic/some", lang.hitch(this, function() {
       // your callback logic here
   }));
   ```
2. the method of widget:

   ```
   topic.subscribe("topic/some", lang.hitch(this, "callbackMethod"));
   ```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/N7NGB/